# Euler Project 2 in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am going through the Odin Project and part of that is doing questions 1-3 in the Euler project.  I am stumped on question 2: 
"By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms."

I am so frustrated! What am I doing wrong?  Here's what I have so far.  Thanks!

```
function f() {
  var fib = [];
  fib.push(1,2,3);
  var i = fib.length;
  var total = 0;
  while(fib[i] < 4000000) {
    var x = fib[i-2] + fib [i-1];
    if(x % 2 == 0) {
      total += x;
    }
  } return total;
}

console.log(f());
```

Comment: `1,2,3` is not how the fibonacci sequence starts.

Answer (score 1):

The fibonacci sequences starts `1, 1, 2`, not `1, 2, 3`.

Also, your solution looks like it will work, but you are storing every number in the sequence instead of just the last two, so this will gobble memory comparatively.

Answer (score 1):

As [@DLeh notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29803191/791010), the fibonacci sequence starts with 1,1,2 - not 1,2,3.  However, that doesn't change the result of summing the even valued items.  The problem you're having is that at this point:

```
while(fib[i] < 4000000) {
```

`fib[i]` is `undefined`, so the function immediately exits with the total staying at 0.  Also within the while loop, you're not pushing the next item in the sequence into your array.  The below code fixes both of these problems:

```
function f() {
  var fib = [];
  fib.push(1,1);
  var i = fib.length;
  var total = 0;
  while(fib[i-1] < 4000000) {
    var x = fib[i-2] + fib [i-1];
    fib.push(x);
    i = fib.length;
    if(x % 2 == 0) {
      total += x;
    }
  } return total;
}

console.log(f()); //4613732
```

@DLeh also pointed out that you're storing more numbers than needed, this solution works without using the array:

```
function f() {
    var f1 = 1;
    var f2 = 1;
    var total = 0;
    while (f2 < 4000000) {
        var t = f1 + f2;
        if (t % 2 == 0)
            total += t;
        f1 = f2;
        f2 = t;        
    }
    return total;
}
console.log(f()); //4613732
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for grins, note that you can do this problem without any use of `%`, and just `+` operations. Every third value in the sequence is even. That is, `2` is followed by `3` (odd), and then `3 + 2` is `5` (odd), but that sum of two odd numbers gets us back to even (`8`) and the cycle repeats.

Thus:

```
function evenFibTotal(limit) {
    var a = 1, b = 1, c = 2, total = 0;

    while (c < limit) {
        total += c;
        a = b + c;
        b = a + c;
        c = a + b;
    }

    return total;
}
```

On each iteration, the second trailing value is set to the next value in the sequence (`b + c`), and that plus the current one is the first trailing value, and finally the next even Fibonacci number is the sum of those two.

(There's also the closed solution but it's no fun :)

Comment: Oh, nice observation!